# apache httpd high cpu 100% on centos 6.8

Tags: apache, performance, cpu-usage, centos6, httpd.conf

I'm using apache 2.2 on centos 6.8. Sometime some httpd process used 100% as image below:

[Top monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEBXT.png)

I already checked all website's source code and all of them is ok ( no loop, no error, ... ).

and httpd.conf:

```
Timeout 30
KeepAlive Off
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers       8
MaxClients        1000
MinSpareThreads    8
MaxSpareThreads    100
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
RLimitCPU  60 80
```

but I can not find any reason about that issue, pls help, thank so much ^^.